STM32 microcontrollers while(1) speed
I did a test on different micros like STM32F0 G030 F103 F401 and STM32H745.
I know that various units like NVIC, WIC, DWT etc. take the CPU out of the while loop and the CPU is always busy.
But how much?
for example in STM32G030 while(1) runs with ~2 MHz. It means less than ~8% of the total CPU can be used
And in STM32H745 cm4 with 200 MHz, the main loop runs with ~7 MHz.
This means that about 97% of the CPU is busy elsewhere.
Is it almost the same in other ARM processors?
Or is this a weakness in the accumulator of ST microcontrollers?
From a comment:
uint64_t Sample_Conter        = 0 ;
uint64_t Veiw_Sample_Conter   = 0 ;


void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback (TIM_HandleTypeDef * htim)
{
  /* Period in 1000ms */

  Veiw_Sample_Conter = Sample_Conter;
  Sample_Conter = 0;
}

HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT (&htim17);

while (1) {

  ADC_Sample_Conter++;
}



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

What can I say? Your results are completely wrong and useless.

If your code works it means that you did not enable any optimizations otherwise it will be optimized to simple jmp to itself

Why is the test useless?:
The while(1) loop itself takes about 26 clocks to execute. 200MHz / 26 = 7.6
And that is why you observe a "7MHz main loop"
Your micro is almost 100% busy doing the loop, and your conclusions are 100% wrong.

Is it almost the same in other ARM processors? Or is this a weakness
in the accumulator of ST microcontrollers?

No, it is a weakness of your test method, not the processor

The optimization of the variable is of course a failure to use the volatile keyword correctly. But yeah, there are a lot of issues with the interpretation of the results...

The results are not really comparable with each other, due to different features in code/data caching and code prefetching accelerators such as ART.
You also don't say how you configure the clock tree and such subsystems, so the results are what they are and not comparable even if I tried to start an empty project and set the system clock to same speed. All the other info is missing.
How much CPU time interrupts cause is up to you what interrupts you enable and how often they happen.

You try to interpret nonsense tests. It is impossible. The loop itself takes about 26 clocks with -O0. If OP enables optimizations the code will optimize the variable from the main loop.

@0___________ Yes the CPU is 99.99% busy running the loop, but how fast it can run the loop depends on caching and prefetch queues. Their usage, like compiler optimizations, are unknown. The point is, you can't expect two different CPUs to run the same piece of code with same amount of clock cycles due to their architectural differences. We don't even know if code is run from flash or RAM.

100% flash as I do not think, judging from the question, that OP is able to run code from RAM

Thank you all, I understand. Your answers were exactly what I wanted to hear. Program
